# Merging try/catch clauses within super lambda function

Tags: java, try-catch

Don't really know if the title fits the problem that I'm trying to solve but here it goes (feel free to modify it for something that makes more sense).

Actually I'm appending String related operations within a `Consumer`, so that when requested the value is transformed within the chain. However, I see the same exception being thrown in multiple methods and I would like to compress that exact same try/catch clause in an upper level, so that methods only contain the new `Consumer` definition to be appended.

```
    public static class Clazz {

        private Consumer<String> modifications;

        public Clazz() {
            // ...
        }

        public void addOp() {
            this.modifications = modifications.andThen(item -> {
              try {
                  item.toUpperCase();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  // logging and exception handling - Merge in common lambda?
              }
            });
        }

        public void anotherOp() {
            this.modifications = modifications.andThen(item -> {
                try {
                    item.toLowerCase();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // logging and exception handling -- Merge in common lambda?
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Would there be any option to compress all those exception clauses in an upper class? Which is the approach when simplifying lambda try/catch clauses?

Comment: This may be a case for a functional library such as Vavr `Try`.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] that shows how you want to use this?  It looks like you would get an NPE.